# fdisk dowsn't recognize SanDisk USB 3 Ultra Flair

Tags: usb, fdisk, gparted, parted

I went through what I found about this subject in the most of the threads, unfortunately without success. I have the following situation. fdisk or parted doesn't recognize this sanDisk USB flash:

**fdisk -l**

```
root@debian:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Intenso SSD SATA
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b7798

Device     Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   11913215  11911168   5.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2  *    11913216 1000215215 988302000 471.3G 83 Linux
```

**fdisk /dev/sdb**

```
root@debian:~# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.33.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 2 MiB, 2097152 bytes, 4096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x88dde89e

Device     Boot Start   End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048  4095    2048   1M 83 Linux

Command (m for help):
```

**parted /dev/sdb**

```
root@debian:~# parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model:  (file)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2097kB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB  primary

(parted)
```

**df -h**

```
root@debian:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G  2.0M   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  9.7M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       463G  162G  281G  37% /
tmpfs            16G  717M   15G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.2G  4.1M  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1        15G   36M   14G   1% /media/USB/54c3f6a6-033c-434a-a6bc-44d60ba82df8
```

**lsblk**

```
root@debian:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   5.7G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda2   8:2    0 471.3G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1  14.3G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14.3G  0 part /media/USB/54c3f6a6-033c-434a-a6bc-44d60ba82df8
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

**lsusb**

```
root@debian:~# lsusb 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 023: ID 0781:5591 SanDisk Corp. Ultra Flair
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS 5011 fingerprint sensor
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 413c:2006 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:1004 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0765:5010 X-Rite, Inc. X-Rite Pantone Color Sensor
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 5986:026a Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 17ef:6019 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsmod | grep usb**

```
root@debian:~# lsmod | grep usb
btusb                  53248  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
bluetooth             647168  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
usb_storage            73728  2 uas
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   135168  2 usbhid,hid_generic
scsi_mod              249856  6 sd_mod,usb_storage,uas,libata,sg,sr_mod
usbcore               294912  9 xhci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,usb_storage,uvcvideo,ehci_hcd,btusb,xhci_pci,uas
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
```

**hdparm -I /dev/sdb**

```
root@debian:~# hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

**smartctl -i /dev/sdb1**

```
root@debian:~# smartctl -i /dev/sdb1
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-9-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SanDisk
Product:              Ultra USB 3.0
Revision:             1.00
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        15,376,318,464 bytes [15.3 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Serial number:        4C530000080316205084
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Sat Jun 20 17:35:53 2020 CEST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported
```

```
root@debian:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
15873+0 records in
15872+0 records out
16643719168 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 4.11023 s, 4.0 GB/s
root@debian:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Intenso SSD SATA
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b7798

Device     Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   11913215  11911168   5.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2  *    11913216 1000215215 988302000 471.3G 83 Linux


root@debian:~#
```

So basically the flash is 16GB, but neither `fdisk` nor `parted` nor `gparted` recognize it. In `Nautilus` ist is mounted as a 15 GB volume. The device information is in `dmesg` as well.
I tried to delete the partition, creating fat32, ntfs, and even using a Windows machine for that, but I still have this weird behavior.
I can use the flash as a 15GB volume, but I am very interested to know the explanation.

Thanks in advanced.

### responses to comments and answers

```
root@debian:~# ls -l /dev/sdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16643719168 Jun 20 18:28 /dev/sdb

root@debian:~# blockdev --getsz /dev/sdb
32507264

root@debian:~# ls -l /dev/sdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16643719168 Jun 20 18:50 /dev/sdb

root@debian:~# df -h /dev
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109678/discussion-on-question-by-max-fdisk-dowsnt-recognize-sandisk-usb-3-ultra-flair).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that (for whatever reason) `/dev/sdb` is not a device file but a regular file. Both the output of `ls -l` (`-rw-r--r--`) and `parted` (`Model:  (file)`) schow that.

This can be fixed by deleting and recreating `/dev/sdb` (the file):

```
rm /dev/sdb
mknod /dev/sdb b 8 16
```

Comment: @Max, I have seen similar cases, where the solution was simple: Remove that `/dev/sdb` file which might have been created by mistake for example if you tried to clone from an iso file to a non-existing block device.

Comment: @sudodus: you got it. I just deleted the file `/dev/sdb` and that's it. remounted it and created an anew partition with `ext4` file system. It is now recognized. Thanks to every one who tried to help on this and special thanks to @Hauke Laging and @sudodus.